# 'The kernel for server .... appears to have died' when using %%R in Jupyter Notebook - what can I do?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am executing the following code

```
%%R -i data_mat -i input_groups -o size_factors
require(scran)

size_factors = computeSumFactors(data_mat, clusters=input_groups, min.mean=0.1)
```

...then it takes the kernel ~25 min to work and give me the following as output:

*Kernel Restarting
The Kernel for... appears to have died. It will restart automatically*

I already tried using `pip install ipykernel --upgrade` - but nothing seems to change when executing the code..